# Creating a global variable to be used in other functions

Tags: javascript, global-variables, javascript-objects

Can someone explain to me why 'currentPos.LatLng' is undefined when I try to access it outside the function even though it is part of an object? Basically I'm trying to be able to grab the values for my current position so I can use them again in another function. Pretty new to this stuff... thanks in advance.

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var currentPos = {
};
var city = new google.maps.LatLng(60, -105);

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: city,
        zoom: 13
    });

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(pos);
                currentPos.LatLng = pos;
                console.log(currentPos.LatLng);
            }, 
            function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(true);
            }
        );          
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
            var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }
    }
    var request = {
                location: city,
                radius: 2500,
                types: ['store']
            };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   
console.log(currentPos.LatLng);
```

Comment: try:

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function logLatLng() { console.log(currentPos.LatLng); });`

Answer (score 2):

Because `initialize` has not yet been called / finished by the time you try to log it.

You'll want to move this, or whatever you're actually looking to do (or calls to other functions that will access `currentPos` once it is populated), inside of the callback / after where you assign it.